# Why does std::prev() applied to a QSet<int*> iterator give me a segfault?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qt5.15, qset

I have Debian 11 amd64, Qt 5.15.2, and try to use `std::prev(it.end())` to get the last element in a `QSet`, like this:

```
#include <QSet>

int main() {
    return *(int*)(*(std::prev(QSet<int*>({new int(10)}).end())));
}
```

But when I run this, I experience a segfault.

If I change `std::prev()` to `operator--`, all works perfectly - I get a return code of 10, as expected (the last item of the set I created is `int*` to 10). But `operator--` is deprecated in Qt 5.15.

It probably works nice on different Qt versions, but my goal is to make this exact version of Qt working.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

P.S. You may check a ready-to-use demo code snippet at https://github.com/makise-homura/qt-crash-test if you need.

Comment: Are you sure that `QSet::iterator` actually meets the requirements of a [bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)? The fact that `operator--` is deprecated/removed strongly suggests that it's not

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to use a C-style cast you should be thinking "I'm probably doing something wrong".

Comment: "P.S. You may check a ready-to use demo code snippet at https://github.com/makise-homura/qt-crash-test , if you need" - better would be to include your example directly *in* the question in [mre] form. Questions should be self contained and not rely on external links.

Comment: `std::prev()` requires a bi-directional iterator that supports `operator--`, but the Qt 5.15 docs say `QSet::iterator::operator--` is "*deprecated in order to align with std::unordered_set functionality*", and `std::unordered_set` only supports forward iteration, not backward iteration. `QSet::iterator::operator--` (as well as `QSet::reverse_iterator` and `QSet::rbegin()`) was removed in a later Qt version. So you are trying to accomplish something that `QSet` simply does not support to begin with.

Comment: Why do you care about getting the last element specifically? `QSet` doesn't store elements in any particular order, the last element is some random element that just happens to be there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of your code is that you are dereferencing a pointer without checking whether it is valid or not. In C++, it's crucial to ensure that you only dereference valid pointers to avoid undefined behavior.

I didn't understand why did you return it in main function but you can write it like this:

```
#include <QSet>
#include <iostream>

int  main()
{
    QSet<int *>  mySet{ new int(10) };

    if (!mySet.isEmpty())
    {
        int *ptr = *mySet.begin();     
        int  a   = *ptr;      // Dereference the pointer to get the value

        std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Set is empty." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and comment of @RemyLebeau is **True**,because of that I use `*mySet.begin()`.

in Qt 5.14.0 or older you can write it like this,I test it and works.

```
#include <QSet>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QSet<int*> mySet;
    mySet.insert(new int(10));

    if (!mySet.isEmpty()) {
        auto it = std::prev(mySet.end());
        if (*it != nullptr) {
            int a = *(*it);
            std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Pointer is null." << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Set is empty." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you mentioned earlier, QSet does not maintain an order of elements, and there is no inherent concept of a "last" element in a QSet.

To work with a `QSet`, if you need to access elements based on some order, you would need to manage that order separately, perhaps by maintaining an auxiliary data structure like a `QList` or `QVector` to keep track of the **order** in which elements were added to the set. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
#include <QSet>
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>

int  main()
{
    QSet<int *>   mySet;
    QList<int *>  insertionOrder;   // To maintain insertion order

    mySet.insert(new int(10));
    insertionOrder.append(new int(10));

    mySet.insert(new int(20));
    insertionOrder.append(new int(20));

    mySet.insert(new int(30));
    insertionOrder.append(new int(30));

    if (!mySet.isEmpty())
    {
        int *lastElement = insertionOrder.last();

        std::cout << "Last element: " << *lastElement << std::endl;

        // Don't forget to clean up the dynamically allocated memory
        delete lastElement;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Set is empty." << std::endl;
    }

    // Clean up remaining elements in mySet and insertionOrder
    for (auto element : mySet)
    {
        delete element;
    }

    insertionOrder.clear();

    return 0;
}
```